# mvcSiteMapProvider external link incorrect on live site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

With reference to the documentation ['Controlling URL behavior'](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Controlling-URL-Behavior#using-protocol-and-hostname-properties-to-make-absolute-urls), I have multiple sites and the logical structure has some of the nodes from one site under another.

So I have a sitemap in each site which represents this. When running in debug, it works fine and the breadcrumb links are ok - using the controller/action/preservedRouteParameters/hostName. BUT when deployed to the live site, an extra part is added to the link.

e.g. In DEBUG - From site 2 (localhost:1234) a link will resolve to 'site1(localhost:5678)/Controller/Action/PreservedRouteParameter

Where as In RELEASE - From site 2 (www.site2.com/events) a link will resolve to 'site1(www.site1.com)/**events/**Controller/Action/PreservedRouteParameter

so my question - is there a solution to my problem (having the extra events in there?

Comment: Expecting: {hostname}/{Controller}/{Action}/{id}

Comment: Getting {hostname}/EXTRA/{Controller}/{Action}/{id}

Comment: What is the extra events information? Could you provide the code to reproduce the problem you are having?

Comment: @NightOwl888 - i've created a [link](https://github.com/SimonLegg/MvcSiteMapProvider_TwoSiteExample)(GitHub repository) and it shows the issue I am having (ok running locally but not when published to a server with extra part in hostname (e.g. /EXTRA or /Site1). In answer to your question re: events.... is the folder on the server that the application is contained in. There are multiple sites/applications in the solution.

Comment: @NightOwl888 - I found a work around for this. Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 0):

WORK AROUND

I couldn't figure this one out. I did however come up with a way around this....

- Create a new controller (or use existing)
- Use redirect:

```
public ActionResult myRedirectAction(int id)
{
    return Redirect("http:localhost:1234/Controller/myAction/" + id);
}
```